# Query returns too few rows

Tags: sql, mysql

setup:

```
mysql> create table product_stock(
       product_id integer, qty integer);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

mysql> create table product(
       product_id integer, product_name varchar(255));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> insert into product(product_id, product_name) 
       values(1, 'Apsana White DX Pencil');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into product(product_id, product_name) 
       values(2, 'Diamond Glass Marking Pencil');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into product(product_id, product_name) 
       values(3, 'Apsana Black Pencil');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into product_stock(product_id, qty) 
       values(1, 100);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
```

my first query:

```
mysql> SELECT IFNULL(SUM(s.qty),0) AS stock, 
              product_name 
       FROM product_stock s 
        INNER JOIN product p ON p.product_id=s.product_id 
       GROUP BY product_name 
       ORDER BY product_name;
```

returns:

```
+-------+---------------------------+ 
| stock | product_name              | 
+-------+---------------------------+ 
| 100   | Apsana White DX Pencil    | 
+-------+---------------------------+ 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I want to have the following result:

```
+-------+------------------------------+ 
| stock | product_name                 | 
+-------+------------------------------+ 
|   0   | Apsana Black Pencil          | 
| 100   | Apsana White DX Pencil       | 
|   0   | Diamond Glass Marking Pencil | 
+-------+------------------------------+
```

To get this result what mysql query should I run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flip your join around and use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(s.qty),0) AS stock, product_name
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN product_stock AS s ON p.product_id=s.product_id
GROUP BY product_name
ORDER BY product_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

An INNER join will only return rows that have a match in both tables. Which is why results for which there are no row in the stock table returns no results.

A LEFT join will return all rows in the first table, and a RIGHT join will return all rows in the second table.

In your query you are expecting all results from the second table, so change your INNER join to a RIGHT join.

There is a tutorial here, with some examples:

http://www.wellho.net/mouth/158_MySQL-LEFT-JOIN-and-RIGHT-JOIN-INNER-JOIN-and-OUTER-JOIN.html

Comment: Very good explanation. Thanks Andre. If I want to join all rows from both the tables then what should I do?

Comment: To return all results from both tables you would need something called a 'FULL OUTER JOIN', but unfortunately MySQL does not support this type of join directly. However, you can emulate it with two joins: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join

Comment: Dear Andre, now I add another field in stock table called branch_id. When I use where clause only matching rows are returned. Is there any way to return all rows from product table where a particular branch_id in stock table?

Answer (score 1):

Do an outer join from `product` to `product_stock`, not an inner join from `product_stock` to `product`.

(Good work on making the question clear, complete, and unambiguous.)

Answer (score 0):

If I've read your question right, all you need to do is change your `INNER JOIN` into a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the stock table as a base, then you'll only get one item, since it only has 1 point of reference to the other table.

Use the product table and join into the stock table. You'll probably get NULL as a stock value but you can handle that with server side code.

Comment: I need some more complex task to do. So I need the result as I requested.